# Qt - Display a QChartView in a QDialog window

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have been following [this example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-linechart-example.html) to try create a line chart in a QDialog window. Instead of adding the chart to the UI with:

```
window.setCentralWidget(chartView);
```

I am adding it to the UI with this line:

```
QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart, ui->widget_chart);
```

I have a QWidget called widget_chart added to my UI file and a horizontal layout applied. The chart is shown but it is very small. I would have expected that by applying the layout, the chart would take up the full width of the window. And that it would be dynamically resize if I resized the window.

[Screenshot of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZjuM.png)

How can I make it so that the chart takes up the full width of the QWidget?

Here is the full code for my dialog.cpp file:

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include <QtCharts>

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QLineSeries *series = new QLineSeries();

    series->append(0, 6);
    series->append(2, 4);
    series->append(3, 8);
    series->append(7, 4);
    series->append(10, 5);

    QChart *chart = new QChart();
    chart->legend()->hide();
    chart->addSeries(series);
    chart->createDefaultAxes();
    chart->setTitle("Simple line chart example");

    QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart, ui->widget_chart);
    chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by **Wojciech Piątek** worked for me. As far as **A_Noonan** is concerned the only thing you need to change is to find out what is the main layout in your ui file and reference it like this

```
ui->main_layout->addWidget(chartView);
```

here you should change **main_layout** to whatever your layout name is. Also doing this way you don't need to have this line:

```
QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart, ui->widget_chart);
```

anymore, instead you can use the regular one.

```
QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
```

also make sure to delete the widget_chart from the ui_file.
There is no other way around this.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the size of the chart view, I am using PyQt5 but I think they have the same syntax for the library.

```
    chartView = QChartView(chart, self)
    chartView.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
    chartView.resize(self.size())

    mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
    mainLayout.addWidget(chartView, 5)
```

Instead of using self, you would use the 'this' operator.

```
    chartView.resize(this->size())
```

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem. I resolved it using layouts. Create layout for your `QWidget`, and then add `QChartView` using `addWidget` function:

```
your_layout->addWidget(chartView)
```